# Meteor: Initializing an object and providing a path to a css file

Tags: meteor

I am looking to add epiceditor to my meteor project which is a javascript embed-able markdown editor. http://epiceditor.com/

In the initialization options you have to provide the base path to the css folder that the editor depends on. Like so:

```
var opts = {
  container: 'epiceditor',
  textarea: null,
  basePath: 'epiceditor',
  clientSideStorage: true,
  localStorageName: 'epiceditor',
  useNativeFullscreen: true,
  parser: marked,
  file: {
    name: 'epiceditor',
    defaultContent: '',
    autoSave: 100
  },
  theme: {
    base: '/themes/base/epiceditor.css',
    preview: '/themes/preview/preview-dark.css',
    editor: '/themes/editor/epic-dark.css'
  }
```

From the Docs:

basepath: The base path of the directory containing the /themes.

I currently keep all my files.css in a stylesheet folder, in my apps root directory. How do I provide a path to the stylesheet in my meteor app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using EpicEditor in my blog.

You need to copy those css files to `public` dir and specify relative paths accordingly:

```
...
basePath:'/css',
theme: {
            base: '/themes/base/epiceditor.css',
            editor: '/themes/editor/epic-dark.css',
            preview: '/themes/preview/github.css'
        },
```

...

and files should be put to dirs:

```
public/css/themes/base/epiceditor.css
public/css/themes/editor/epic-dark.css
public/css/themes/preview/github.css
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `epiceditor` css files in `/public` and then specify the path relative to that.

To use the paths you specified in `opts` it would look like this.

```
|-- client
|-- server
|-- private
|-- public
|   |-- epiceditor
|   |   |-- themes
|   |   |   |-- base
|   |   |   |   |-- epiceditor.css
|   |   |   |   |-- preview-dark.css
|   |   |   |   `-- epic-dark.css
```

Comment: thanks for giving the paths for the options i provided. I can see the the base theme folder is the folder in the public directory.